# How to iterate through array list and add or remove Object based on conditions?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

So I'm making a few classes that handle a collection of DVD Objects. My add and remove methods are supposed to do this:

add – this method is used to add a new DVD. It should have five parameters that
represent the title, category, running time, year, and price of a DVD. If the title is already in the DVD collection, there is no need to add or change anything.Otherwise, the DVD is added to the collection. It returns the DVD entry if it is already in the DVD collection, or returns null if a new one is added.

remove – this method should have a title as the parameter. It should remove the
DVD from the collection if the title is found. It returns the DVD entry which was removed, or returns null if the title is not found.

My methods currently work only for the first object in my text file but when I type in another object further down the file, It just returns null.

My text file contains the following 6 objects.
Adam
Documentary
78 minutes
2012
7.99
Choo Choo
Documentary
60 minutes
2006
11.99
Good Morning America
Documentary
80 minutes
2010
9.99
Life is Beautiful
Drama
125 minutes
1999
15.99
Morning Bird
Comic
150 minutes
2008
17.99
Mystic River
Mystery
130 minutes
2002
24.99

```
public DVD add(String titlez, String categoryz, String runTimez, String yearz, String pricez) {
            Iterator<DVD> it = arraylist.iterator();
            DVD dvd = it.next();
            if(dvd.getTitle().equals(titlez)){
            return dvd;
        }
        else{
            DVD dvd1 = new DVD (titlez, categoryz, runTimez, yearz, pricez);
            arraylist.add(dvd1);

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DVD remove(String title) {
        Iterator<DVD> it = arraylist.iterator();
        DVD dvd =  it.next();
        if(dvd.getTitle().equals(title)){
            arraylist.remove(dvd);
            return dvd;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code does not compile in its current form.

Comment: First question.   What do you want your add method to do?  Forget the code, please describe what you would like it to do.

Comment: Its literally posted right next a the method name and a hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` method is not iterating through the list; it's just testing the first element. (It would also throw an exception if your list was empty.) Try this instead, which iterates through the entire list before deciding that the title is not present. (I'm using the [*enhanced* `for` *loop*](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) syntax instead of a traditional `for` loop.)

```
public DVD add(String titlez, String categoryz, String runTimez, String yearz, String pricez) {
    for (DVD dvd : arrayList) {
        if(dvd.getTitle().equals(titlez)){
            return dvd;
        }
    }
    DVD dvd1 = new DVD (titlez, categoryz, runTimez, yearz, pricez);
    arraylist.add(dvd1);

    return null;
}
```

Your `remove` method has a similar problem. Use this instead:

```
public DVD remove(String title) {
    for (DVD dvd : arrayList) {
        if (dvd.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            arrayList.remove(dvd);
            return dvd;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this is style is a bit dangerous. Normally, you shouldn't modify a list while iterating through it. If the iteration continued, you'd get a `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown. However, since you also stop iterating immediately upon modifying the list, it should be okay. There are two ways to avoid an exception and still modify the list. (1) use a `ListIterator` instead of an `Iterator`, because `ListIterator` has it's own `remove()` method you can use. You'd have to go back to a traditional `for` loop syntax. (2) defer the removal until iteration is done, like this:

```
public DVD remove(String title) {
    DVD toRemove = null;
    for (DVD dvd : arrayList) {
        if (dvd.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            toRemove = dvd;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (toRemove != null) {
        arrayList.remove(toRemove);
    }
    return toRemove;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not looping on entire list try to use this instead:

```
Iterator<DVD> it = arraylist.iterator();    
while(it.hasNext()) {
    DVD dvd =  it.next();
    if(dvd.getTitle().equals(title)){
        arraylist.remove(dvd);
        return dvd;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thank you, so I thought about using a for loop but was having some difficulty, however while didn't come to mind.

Comment: You are welcome, you can also use `for each` as in **Ted Hopp**'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already "answered", you are not iterating through the whole list.

I have refactored your code to make the add and remove methods cleaner.  I have created a POJO (plain old java object) DVD, and a DVDService which has a DVDStore.

The DVDStore stores a DVD using the titlez as its "key".  The add and remove methods use an exists method to check if the DVD key is in the DVDStore.

I return true of false for add or remove.  I try and add a new DVD "film1" twice, and then remove twice.

The output from running is here:

```
film1 has been added = true
film1 has been added = false
film1 has been removed = true
film1 has been removed = false
```

I have removed the iterator you are using, and search the HashMap for the "titlez" key.  I also return a "simple boolean" for add and remove.  Has add or remove been successful (true or false).

This makes add and remove easy to understand, and maintain.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class DVD {
    private String titlez;
    private String categoryz;
    private String runTimez;
    private String yearz;
    private String price;

    /**
     * DVD constructor
     *
     * @param titlez - title
     * @param categoryz - category
     * @param runTimez - length of file
     * @param yearz - year made
     * @param price - price
     */
     DVD(String titlez, String categoryz, String runTimez, String yearz, String price) {
        this.titlez = titlez;
        this.categoryz = categoryz;
        this.runTimez = runTimez;
        this.yearz = yearz;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * get DVD titlez
     * @return - DVD titlez
     */
    String getTitlez() {
        return titlez;
    }
}


public class DVDService {
    private Map<String, DVD> dvdStore; // DVD store - use DVD titlez to "look     up" DVD

    /**
     * Convenience method for checking if a title exists in our DVD Store
     * @param titlez - DVD title
     * @return - true if exists in DVD store
     */
     private boolean exists(String titlez) {
        return dvdStore.containsKey(titlez);
     }


    /**
     * Add a DVD to the DVD store
     * @param dvd - DVD to be added
     * @return - true if DVD added
     */
       private boolean add(DVD dvd) {
           if (dvdStore == null) {  // if DVD store is null - create it
               dvdStore = new HashMap<>();
           }

           // if title does NOT exist - add it to the DVD store and return true
           if (!exists(dvd.getTitlez())) {
               dvdStore.put(dvd.getTitlez(), dvd);
               return true;
           }

           return false; // title already exists
        }


    /**
     * Remove DVD from DVD store
     * @param dvd - DVD to be removed
     * @return - true if DVD removed
     */
    private boolean remove(DVD dvd) {
        if (exists(dvd.getTitlez())) {
            dvdStore.remove(dvd.getTitlez());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DVD dvd = new DVD("film1", "Mystery", "2 hours", "1971", "2.00");

        DVDService dvdService = new DVDService();

        /**
         * Add a DVD = true
         * Add again = false as it exists in the DVD store
         *
         * Remove DVD = true as it exists
         * Remove DVD = false as it no longer exists
         */

        System.out.printf("%s has been added = %s\n", dvd.getTitlez(), dvdService.add(dvd));

        System.out.printf("%s has been added = %s\n", dvd.getTitlez(), dvdService.add(dvd));

        System.out.printf("%s has been removed = %s\n", dvd.getTitlez(), dvdService.remove(dvd));

        System.out.printf("%s has been removed = %s", dvd.getTitlez(), dvdService.remove(dvd));
    }
}
```